# Receive data of json from mlab database

Tags: json, mongoose, mlab

So currently i have this

```
var MongoClient = require ('mongoose'); 
var database;   
function connectDB()
    {   console.log("connecting mongo database...");
        var databaseUrl = 'mongodb://twt:123>@ds117316.mlab.com:17316/tweet';
        MongoClient.connect(databaseUrl,function(err,db){
        console.log("Connected to DataBase:"+ databaseUrl);
        var cursor = db.collection().find({}, { _id: false, lat: true, lon: true });
        cursor.each(function(err, doc)
        {  
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(doc);

        });

        database = db;
        });
    }
```

On the mlab database I have Database:tweet on collections i have twmsg and i have users. I am trying to retrieve data from twmsg both longitude and latitudes
stored it as "lat" and "lon" not sure what i did wrong to get an error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined

Comment: You are not checking for errors after connecting. You have no idea if you are connected or not.

Comment: (node:9776) DeprecationWarning: `open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, use `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using `connect()` or `createConnection()`. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#use-mongo-client
Db.prototype.authenticate method will no longer be available in the next major release 3.x as MongoDB 3.6 will only allow auth against users in the admin db and will no longer allow multiple credentials on a socket. Please authenticate using MongoClient.connect with auth credentials.
Connected to db
                      looks like i am connected

Answer (score 0):

nvm i found the error it was after password i added > basically typed in wrong password which is why it wasn't connected. Also need to change to

```
MongoClient.connect(databaseUrl,{useMongoClient:true},function(err,db)
```

because mongoose changed when they had update so need to add {useMongoClient:true}